# C# Multipart/Related Parsing and Attachments

Tags: c#, multipart

I am getting a post of Content-type Multipart/Related with an xml body with mainly PDF file attachments.

Is there a C# assembly that will handle the parsing of a post like this, where I can pull the attachments out with the purpose of saving them.

I have it done for Multipart/PostData, but it has to be for Multipart/Related.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "post", I get the feeling you are talking about an HTTP POST request?

Normally, for multipart/related (which tends to be *email* related), I would recommend my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library.

You could still use my MimeKit library to parse HTTP POST requests since MIME is MIME, but you could also take a look at [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Http/WebUtilities/src) which has a MultipartReader class that will likely work great for this.

Comment: I am getting a 'Failed to parse message headers' exception. Below is the message header:          POST /JaggaerWeb/JaggaerWeb.ashx HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2450640
Content-Type: multipart/related; start-info="\"text/xml\""; type="application/xop+xml"; start="\"<1629377607719.-4329274944222426429@sciquest.com>\""; boundary="----=Mime1629377607719.-4329274944222426429"
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Basic amFnZ2FlcjohQHNhdHVyblBsdXRvNDY1
Host: wd-contentrelay.msmyid.uga.edu
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_281)

Comment: You need to skip over the HTTP-specific stuff like `"POST /JaggaerWeb/JaggaerWeb.ashx HTTP/1.1\r\n"`